# What are overlapping subproblems in Dynamic Programming (DP)?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, divide-and-conquer, kadanes-algorithm

There are two key attributes that a problem must have in order for dynamic programming to be applicable: **optimal substructure** and **overlapping subproblems** [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). For this question, we going to focus on the latter property only.

There are various definitions for **overlapping subproblems**, two of which are:

- *A problem is said to have overlapping subproblems if the problem can be broken down into subproblems which are reused several times **OR** a recursive algorithm for the problem solves the same subproblem over and over rather than always generating new subproblems* [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems).
- *A second ingredient that an optimization problem must have for dynamic programming to apply is that the space of subproblems must be "small" in the sense that a recursive algorithm for the problem solves the same subproblems over and over, rather than always generating new subproblems* (*Introduction to Algorithms* by CLRS)

Both definitions (and lots of others on the internet) seem to boil down to a problem having overlapping subproblems if finding its solution involves solving the same subproblems multiple times. In other words, there are many small sub-problems which are computed many times during finding the solution to the original problem. A classic example is the Fibonacci algorithm that lots of examples use to make people understand this property.

Until a couple of days ago, life was great until I discovered **Kadane's algorithm which made me question the overlapping subproblems definition**. This was mostly due to the fact that people have different views on whether or NOT it is a DP algorithm:

- [Dynamic programming aspect in Kadane's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16324315/3385411)
- [Is Kadane's algorithm consider DP or not? And how to implement it recursively?](https://www.quora.com/Is-Kadanes-algorithm-consider-DP-or-not-And-how-to-implement-it-recursively)
- [Is Kadane's Algorithm Greedy or Optimised DP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155269/is-kadanes-algorithm-greedy-or-optimised-dp)
- [Dynamic Programming vs Memoization (see my comment)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/99517/127532)

The most compelling reason why someone wouldn't consider Kadane's algorithm a DP algorithm is that each subproblem would only **appear and be computed once** in a recursive implementation [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16324315/3385411), hence it doesn't entail the overlapping subproblems property. However, lots of articles on the internet consider Kadane's algorithm to be a DP algorithm, which made me question my understanding of what **overlapping subproblems** means in the first place.

People seem to interpret the **overlapping subproblems property** differently. It's easy to see it with simple problems such as the Fibonacci algorithm but things become very unclear once you introduce Kadane's algorithm for instance. I would really appreciate it if someone could offer some further explanation.

Comment: I don't think you should concern yourself too much with whether a given algorithm qualifies as "dynamic programming" or not. "Dynamic programming" is helpful as a paradigm to design algorithms. It is not useful as a label to put on existing algorithms. You cite the Fibonacci sequence as an example. Many people would disagree on whether an implementation of Fibonacci which only keeps the previous two values in memory qualifies as "dynamic programming" or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've read so much about this already.  The only thing I have to add is this:

The overlapping subproblems in Kadane's algorithm are here:

max_subarray = max( from i=1 to n [ **max_subarray_to(i)** ] )

max_subarray_to(i) = max(**max_subarray_to(i-1)** + array[i], array[i])

As you can see, max_subarray_to() is evaluated twice for each i.  Kadane's algorithm memoizes these, turning it from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n)

... But as @Stef says, it doesn't matter what you call it, as long as you understand it.

Comment: I think you just blew my mind! So many people couldn't demonstrate the recursive relation for Kadane's algorithm that made the overlapping subproblems obvious. I think in most examples `max_subarray_to` was specified but never `max_subarray`, so thanks for that! So the overlapping subproblems property that I questioned is indeed correct, but I failed to see how subproblems are re-evaluated multiple times in Kadane's algorithm.

Comment: I would argue that this isn't overlapping subproblems in the spirit of DP, this is just the programmer being silly for abusing recursion instead of storing the return values of `max_subarray_to`. Consider exponentiation by squaring where you usually do something like `t = pow(x, n/2); return t*t;`. But I can do `return pow(x,n/2)*pow(x,n/2)`, is this DP or just me doing the obvious and storing the return value of the recursive call? I would say it's the latter. A real DP algorithm will have expo runtime if implemented recursively without memoization. IMO, this just forces the definition.